# How to do an arithmetic operation with aliased column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I have a databse table as like below:

```
id received_by sent_by amount product_id
1  1           2       10     1
2  1           3       12     1
3  2           1       5      1
4  3           1       8      2
```

Here, `received_by` and `sent_by` are two user ID those who are receiving and sending the product respectively. I want to calculate the total amount of each product of a single user by subtracting the sent amount from received amount.
My current query looks like below:

```
select
    product_id,
    (received - sent) as quantity,
    case(when received_by = 1 then amount end) as received,
    case(when sent_by = 1 then amount end) as sent
group by
    product_id;
```

Here I get an error that `Unknown column 'received' in 'field list'`.

How can I calculate each users inventory/stock?

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: Please share your desired output data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the calculated columns in the `SELECT` list.
Also you need the aggregate function `SUM()`.

One way to do it is with a subquery:

```
select *, (received - sent) as quantity
from (
  select product_id, 
         sum(case when received_by = 1 then amount else 0 end) as received, 
         sum(case when sent_by = 1 then amount else 0 end) as sent 
  from tablename
  where 1 in (received_by, sent_by)
  group by product_id
) t
```

Or:

```
select product_id, 
       sum(case when received_by = 1 then amount else -amount end) as quantity,
       sum(case when received_by = 1 then amount else 0 end) as received, 
       sum(case when sent_by = 1 then amount else 0 end) as sent 
from tablename
where 1 in (received_by, sent_by)
group by product_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c9505de237485bff6d253897c4b1f7de).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you missed the from clause in your query before group by. Secondly you cannot use column aliases (received, sent) in same select statement.

```
 create table mytable(id int, received_by int, sent_by int, amount int, product_id int);
 insert into mytable values(1,  1,           2,       10,     1);
 insert into mytable values(2,  1,           3,       12,     1);
 insert into mytable values(3,  2,           1,       5,      1);
 insert into mytable values(4,  3,           1,       8,      2);
```

Query:

```
  select product_id, (coalesce(received,0)-coalesce(sent,0)) as Quantity, coalesce(received,0) received,coalesce(sent)sent
from 
(       select
            product_id,
            sum(case when received_by = 1 then amount end) as received,
            sum(case when sent_by = 1 then amount end) as sent
        from mytable
        group by
            product_id

)t;
```

Output:

```
    |product_id | Quantity | received | sent|
    |-----------|----------|----------|-----|
    |         1 |       17 |       22 |    5|
    |         2 |       -8 |        0 |    8|
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0030e4ea3c6cf61473a2ef95ea4c7cd)*